# Best way to store a single user in an Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, sharedpreferences

I'd like my app to allow a single user to create a profile that is accessed every time they run the app. The user's profile contains a String entry and five int entries. I've thought about using an SQLite database to store the info between sessions, but it seems like overkill since I'd only need one row in a single table to store the data. However, I'm not sure if it's possible to use SharedPreferences on a String type of data.

Can anyone provide some insight into this issue please? Thank you!

Comment: You would find the answer to your "unsure" in the shared preferences documentation quite easily.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can use `SharedPreferences`.

**To write**

```
Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("file_name", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.clear();
editor.putString("pref_name", myStringValue);
editor.commit();
```

**To read back**

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("file_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
String myStringValue = preferences.getString("pref_name", "default_value");
```

Regards.

Comment: Thanks Luis, that sounds perfect. I appreciate it!